# Sort the output of find before piping to openssh

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, files, find

I'm using this command to recursively generate a [SHA-512 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) for each file in a directory hierarchy:

```
find . -type f -exec openssl sha512 {} \;
```

I'd like to sort the files in lexicographical order before generating the hashes.

I can use `sort` like this:

```
find . -type f | sort
```

but I'm not sure how to then pipe the sorted file list into `openssl`.  I tried this:

```
find . -type f | sort | openssl sha512
```

but this generates a single hash of the entire output of `sort`, whereas I want a hash for each individual file.

`find` in some versions of bash includes an `-s` option ("Cause `find` to traverse the file hierarchies in lexicographical order"), but this isn't available in my version of `find`.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `xargs` to get what you want.

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 -n1 openssl sha512
```

The `-n1` option tells xargs to only allow one argument to be given to the `openssl` command.  The `-print0`, `-z` and `-0` options prevent the pipeline from breaking if there are "problem" characters (like an embedded newline) in the filenames.

Comment: Many thanks, that works perfectly! I haven't used `xargs` before, but I can see it's very useful for situations like this. It's great to learn that `find`, `sort` and `xargs` all have support for null-terminated items, so they can all be combined in a single pipeline like this!

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it to xargs -L 1 openssl sha512, like this:

```
find . -type f | sort | xargs -L 1 openssl sha512
```

xargs takes outputs and runs it as the command line of the program, the "-L 1" limits it to one line per execution.